# Replace custom fileds with DocuSign placeholders

Tags: c#, docusignapi

There is an document that I am sending to DocuSign over REST API. In document I have defined custom field for signing - signhere_{r}.

When client opens uploaded document on DocuSign, she finds Signature placeholder (DocuSign arrow) above the signhere_{1} text that is part of the document. What I would like is that user finds only DocuSign's placeholder,  not mine any more. I can reach/hack that by coloring my custom tag in white. I guess that there is better built in solution.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your create envelope call? your tag value shouldn't be showing on the document unless you're using Anchor tags, in which case the white text would be the answer to cover the Anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your anchor string to the same color as the background is probably the best solution here, the DocuSign Developer Center mentions this in on the tabs features page (see the Tab Positioning section):

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs

Keep in mind that you can also do offsets (ie place tab 5 inches above and 1 inch to the right) of whatever anchorStrings you want to use, whether they are visible or not to the signer.